# How do I correct error 1 positional argument missing, where a class instance is an attribute of an instance of another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I correct this TypeError in Python 3.x stating that 1 required positional argument is missing for a function call to an attribute of an instance of a class, where that attribute is itself an instance of a different class?

The code appears below, and the error message appears below that. The line of code that the error message indicates is the final line of code.

---

```
class Restaurant:
    """A simple representation of a restaurant."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"Restaurant name: {self.restaurant_name.title()}")
        print(f"Cuisine: {self.cuisine_type}")

toy_cafe = Restaurant("toy cafe", "toy food")
pet_cafe = Restaurant("pet cafe", "pet food")

toy_cafe.describe_restaurant()
print("")

pet_cafe.describe_restaurant()
print("")


class Flavours:
    """Create a class to store a list of flavours."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name):
        self.flavours = ['strawberry', 'chocolate', 'vanilla', 'mint', 'cookies and cream', 'peach', 'mango', 'coconut', 'coffee', 'caramel', 'choc mint', 'lemon', 'choc chip', 'passionfruit']
    
    def show_flavours(self, restaurant_name):
        """prints a list of icecream flavours sold by an icecream stand."""
        print(f"\n{self.restaurant_name.title()} serves these icecream flavours:\n")
        for flavour in flavours:
            print(' -', flavour)

class Icecream_stand(Restaurant):
    """Create a class for icecream stands."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavours_sold = Flavours(self.restaurant_name) 

toy_icecream = Icecream_stand("toy icecream", "icecream")

toy_icecream.flavours_sold.show_flavours()
```

---

```
toy_icecream.flavours_sold.show_flavours()
TypeError: show_flavours() missing 1 required positional argument: 'restaurant_name'
```

---

I have tried putting inside the brackets of the function call everything I can think of
(  such as:  self    self.restaurant_name  restaurant_name   toy_icecream.restaurant_name  )
but the first three of those give NameError: name ' ' is not defined,
and the last one gives AttributeError: 'Flavours' object has no attribute 'restaurant_name'.

How do I fix this code?

And why do each of the arguments I tried putting inside the brackets return those errors?

Thank you!

Comment: change `super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)`  to `super().__init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these problems exist in `Flavours` class. You need to make these modifications:

```
class Flavours:
    """Create a class to store a list of flavours."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name   #<--- add this
        self.flavours = ['strawberry', 'chocolate', 'vanilla', 'mint', 'cookies and cream', 'peach', 'mango', 'coconut', 'coffee', 'caramel', 'choc mint', 'lemon', 'choc chip', 'passionfruit']
    
    def show_flavours(self):   #<--- remove `restaurant_name` from here
        """prints a list of icecream flavours sold by an icecream stand."""
        print(f"\n{self.restaurant_name.title()} serves these icecream flavours:\n")
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print(' -', flavour)
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Restaurant:
    """A simple representation of a restaurant."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"Restaurant name: {self.restaurant_name.title()}")
        print(f"Cuisine: {self.cuisine_type}")

toy_cafe = Restaurant("toy cafe", "toy food")
pet_cafe = Restaurant("pet cafe", "pet food")

toy_cafe.describe_restaurant()
print("")

pet_cafe.describe_restaurant()
print("")


class Flavours:
    """Create a class to store a list of flavours."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name):
        self.flavours = ['strawberry', 'chocolate', 'vanilla', 'mint', 'cookies and cream', 'peach', 'mango', 'coconut', 'coffee', 'caramel', 'choc mint', 'lemon', 'choc chip', 'passionfruit']
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    def show_flavours(self):
        """prints a list of icecream flavours sold by an icecream stand."""
        print(f"\n{self.restaurant_name.title()} serves these icecream flavours:\n")
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print(' -', flavour)

class Icecream_stand(Restaurant):
    """Create a class for icecream stands."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavours_sold = Flavours(self.restaurant_name) 

toy_icecream = Icecream_stand("toy icecream", "icecream")

toy_icecream.flavours_sold.show_flavours()
```

Comment: check it now again i mistakely posted wrong solution deeply sorry for my mistake

Comment: still, dont just post code Tell the person asking the question what you have changed and why you think those modifications were needed.